# Stokes' theorem in higher dimensions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

I'm trying to follow along with Stokes's theorem on [page 46](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Earapura/preprints/diffforms.pdf) and I'm not quite understanding where this comes from: $$ V=\int_{B} dx \wedge dy \wedge dz \wedge dt = - \int_{S} t dx \wedge dy \wedge dz $$

I can understand the negative due to the anticommutivity, $\int_{B} dx \wedge dy \wedge dz \wedge dt = - \int_{B} dt \wedge dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$ due to how there would be three interchanges

But where does the $d$ for the $t$ go? Is it as simple as integrating with respect to $t$ but leaving all the rest the same? (So far, I've only applied $d$ to various forms and so I'm not sure how it works in reverse.

--

I can understand the first line is Stokes' theorem, but how would you know that α is that? I'd know that the volume is $\int_{B} dx \wedge dy \wedge dz \wedge dt = \int_{domain} d\alpha $ and then I'd need α itself to integrate over the surface like $\int_{surface} \alpha$. But how would we get $\alpha$ if given $d\alpha$?

Comment: You've left out definitions of the notation. Presumably $B$ is a compact, oriented $4$-dimensional manifold with boundary, and $S$ is its boundary. This is precisely what Stokes's Theorem says.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly where you applied the Stokes theorem

$$ \int _B d\alpha = \int_S \alpha$$

to $\alpha = -t  dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$, since

\begin{align}
d\alpha &= -d (t  dx \wedge dy \wedge dz) \\
&= -dt \wedge  dx \wedge dy \wedge dz.  
\end{align}

Note that we have the last equality: essentially this is how we define the exterior derivative, but you can also think of it as the application of Leibniz rules

$$ d (t  dx \wedge dy \wedge dz) = dt  \wedge dx \wedge dy \wedge dz \pm t d ( dx \wedge dy \wedge dz)$$
and that $d^2 = 0$, which gives (by some Leibniz rule again)
$$d ( dx \wedge dy \wedge dz) = 0.$$

Comment: I can understand the first line is Stokes' theorem, but how would you know that $\alpha$ is that? I'd know that the volume is $\int_{B} d\alpha = \int_{B} dx \wedge dy \wedge dz \wedge dt$ and then I'd need $\alpha$ itself to integrate over the surface. But how would we get $\alpha$ if given $d\alpha$?

Comment: How do I know? Well, I don't. You give me that. I don't know why you chosen this $\alpha$. May be your surface $S$ make it easier to calculate $\int_S \alpha$? There are infintely many other choice: e.g. $x \wedge dy \wedge dz \wedge dt, zdx \wedge dy  \wedge dt$ both has the same property. @Ally

Comment: Interesting. So it's like how amazingly good substitutions work? That is, there is probably some sort of intuition that makes future calculations work but it's kinda difficult to think why that substitution was initially chosen without having to do it the hard way first and realizing "if only I had made this substitution"

Comment: This not an example of an "amazingly good substitution". This is, instead, literally the problem that you wrote, combined with a calculation of $d(t \, dx \wedge dy \wedge dz)$: $$ \int_{B} \underbrace{dx \wedge dy \wedge dz \wedge dt}_{-d\alpha} = - \int_{S} \underbrace{t \, dx \wedge dy \wedge dz}_\alpha $$